Expressing elliptic $\lambda^*(r)$ with radicals
For some small $r$, the values of $\lambda^*(r)$ can be expressed symbolically, see Elliptic Lambda Function
equations $(11)-(34)$
Is it possible to get some of these expressions using Mathematica?
I tried
Table[Sqrt[ModularLambda[I*Sqrt[r]]], {r, 1, 10}]
(* {1/Sqrt[2], Sqrt[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[2]]], Sqrt[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[3]]], ...} *)

and I get the expected value only for $r=1$.
Equivalently is
Table[EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[-Pi*Sqrt[r]]]^2 / 
  EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[-Pi*Sqrt[r]]]^2, {r, 1, 10}]

also without the expected result. I've tried various combinations of FullSimplify, FunctionExpand, etc.
Verification is only possible numerically, for example if $r=2$ then:
Sqrt[ModularLambda[I*Sqrt[2]]] == Sqrt[2] - 1 // FullSimplify
(* Sqrt[2] == 1 + Sqrt[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[2]]] *)
N[%, 100]
(* True *)


Have you read the paper Selberg, A. and Chowla, S. "On Epstein's Zeta-Function" that was referred to on the MathWorld page?

@azerbajdzan: My goal was not to determine these expressions (this has been known for a long time, as well as the main result of that paper, cited between formulas 10 and 11), but to test whether Mathematica can simplify it. It turns out that it doesn't, although it can be computed by a numerical trick. I would therefore recommend that the authors of Mathematica add these symbolic expressions to the knowledge base (for small r).

So why using numerical computation when you know exact formulas? Just rewrite them in Mathematica and you are done.

@azerbajdzan: I don't want to manually transcribe these expressions from articles, but I want them to be output by Mathematica. And symbolically, numerically is not enough. Further, I consider this discussion a waste of time.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

seq = Table[{r, Sqrt[ModularLambda[I*Sqrt[r]]]}, {r, 1, 12}];

Find approximant roots with RootApproximant
EDIT: As suggested in a comment by Vaclav Kotesovec, increasing the precision (and also using ToRadicals) extends the number of r values that work as desired.
seq2 = seq // N[#, 100] & // RootApproximant // ToRadicals // Simplify;

(seq3 = Select[seq2,
    FreeQ[#, Root] && N[#[[2]] == seq[[#[[1]]]][[2]], 100] &]) //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


Similarly, for the second approach,
seq4 = Table[{r, 
    EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[-Pi*Sqrt[r]]]^2/
     EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[-Pi*Sqrt[r]]]^2}, {r, 1, 12}];

seq5 = seq4 // N[#, 100] & // RootApproximant // ToRadicals // 
   Simplify;

(seq6 = Select[seq5,
    FreeQ[#, Root] && N[#[[2]] == seq4[[#[[1]]]][[2]], 100] &]);

Both approaches give the same results
seq3 === seq6

(* True *)

That is, most of the desired results but not all.

Yes, that's nice. Solution with MinimalPolynomial[RootApproximant[...]] I used in 2018, see https://oeis.org/A084540. But a solution without the need for numerical calculations would be better.

Missing values can be obtained by increasing the numerical precision. For example, for r=5, RootApproximant[N[Sqrt[ModularLambda[I*Sqrt[5]]], 500]] gives an equation of the eighth degree (not the ninth), whose root is already satisfactory.
